# How to tell apt to download the list of upgradable packages one by one?

Tags: apt

During `apt upgrade`, `apt` try to download from 3 to 4 packages at once, here is a sample:

```
71% [133 openjdk-11-jre-headless 4,353 kB/37.3 MB 12%] [74 linux-firmware 55.8 MB/125 MB 45%] [137 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-107-generic 22.9 MB/39.4 MB 58%]
```

Is there a way allowing `apt` to download the list of upgradable packages one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a download speed limit will switch to single download queues:

```
sudo apt -o Acquire::http::Dl-Limit=1000 upgrade
```

You can choose the limit as appropriate; it’s specified in kibibytes per second.